# ansible lineinfile insertafter firstmatch not working

Tags: ansible

I have the following file snippet (Wordpress wp-config)

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

/**#@+
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',          'Zm4X4prz+  Tg=1vTV,!br#e_*syjU6X>/wlzyKI Bk~pWNT}!n.RbU0UxpH=*&z' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',   'U>Mh_#jSBIU;W 58p`0oN9q,+mu2.s9yX^TE|t{%mXUOIXo&+mMQhR5+X5q-]/BY' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',     'BIJvvXpH~72Y>2elZc,X>E~;),Fs%5+u4VJ!J%$pz>Z4Ka%vdnqgp!X[iJ[>+&TS' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',         '%17!A/TG<]]3Df-!z:hC=5_l,U~DA0uq!u1M}fWYeVH?Gty2$iMkLe.%EK(Gi4i&' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',         '1%[D?Gi/wJ$~Pp@VrJUNWh-KQ[QF)LX54pJ=*<B]:eF>PEi^B@db@YfCp])!56ai' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT',  'ILwaki+jmnJ{gGVfCz1b-P|1Iu!UL[>c+h=RdM&-~QXZ0XCGGV]Ipz%W$))<*QLg' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',    ' NO%PlUAjRmWNx6f-dDs-g`&Y~bL^QLzHVInER qq9i #<Ep*`K4@(nm|Fj{Iy}H' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',        'zgfCUhUT3~7QJx{B.(il]%:;W=R}mm4oYmxA_{2k(ILN16no*1x_-cQMo8B._4ny' );
define( 'WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT', 'L1T}Q|CrZ/?L5hw:,6S`~fnS%(6)BjA9Ob2C!j52x+3)+Oa LCgmB{2g^:E1I&1t' );


/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress database table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';


/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */



/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
if ( ! defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) ) {
    define('WP_DEBUG', false);
}

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

I am trying to insert a line straight after the 2nd line in the snippet I am showing:

```
- name: setup wp-config.php WP_DEBUG true
  lineinfile: name=/var/www/{{item.name}}/{{item.document_root}}/wp-config.php regexp="WP_DEBUG" line="define('WP_DEBUG', true);" insertafter="FORCE_SSL_ADMIN" firstmatch=true
  with_items:
    - "{{wordpress_websites}}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  tags:
    - debugon
```

However turns out to be "no change required:"

```
ansible-playbook [core 2.12.1] (detached HEAD f00f12393b) last updated 2022/01/31 06:11:20 (GMT +000)
  config file = /root/mgr2/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /root/ansible2.12/lib/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /root/ansible2.12/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Mar 13 2023, 10:26:41) [GCC 9.4.0]
  jinja version = 2.10.1
  libyaml = True
Using /root/mgr2/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
redirecting (type: inventory) ansible.builtin.aws_ec2 to amazon.aws.aws_ec2

...

<52.65.73.113> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/f4f1406f87 -tt 52.65.73.113 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682325441.6915336-1326380-268585979143964/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<52.65.73.113> (0, b'\r\n{"changed": false, "msg": "", "backup": "", "diff": [{"before": "", "after": "", "before_header": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php (content)", "after_header": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php (content)"}, {"before_header": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php (file attributes)", "after_header": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php (file attributes)"}], "invocation": {"module_args": {"name": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php", "regexp": "WP_DEBUG", "line": "define(\'WP_DEBUG\', true);", "insertafter": "FORCE_SSL_ADMIN", "firstmatch": true, "path": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php", "state": "present", "backrefs": false, "create": false, "backup": false, "unsafe_writes": false, "search_string": null, "insertbefore": null, "validate": null, "mode": null, "owner": null, "group": null, "seuser": null, "serole": null, "selevel": null, "setype": null, "attributes": null}}}\r\n', b'Shared connection to 52.65.73.113 closed.\r\n')
<52.65.73.113> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<52.65.73.113> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/f4f1406f87 52.65.73.113 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682325441.6915336-1326380-268585979143964/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<52.65.73.113> (0, b'', b'')
ok: [52.65.73.113] => (item={'php_fpm_port': 9409, 'name': 'www.test.demohub.site', 'php_version': '7.4', 'user': 'www_testdemohub', 'document_root': 'trunk', 'block': 'no', 'max_children': 1, 'mysql8': True, 'cdn_id': 'EZ0IYUPSOHOR4'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "backup": "",
    "changed": false,
    "diff": [
        {
            "after": "",
            "after_header": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php (content)",
            "before": "",
            "before_header": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php (content)"
        },
        {
            "after_header": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php (file attributes)",
            "before_header": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php (file attributes)"
        }
    ],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backrefs": false,
            "backup": false,
            "create": false,
            "firstmatch": true,
            "group": null,
            "insertafter": "FORCE_SSL_ADMIN",
            "insertbefore": null,
            "line": "define('WP_DEBUG', true);",
            "mode": null,
            "name": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php",
            "owner": null,
            "path": "/var/www/www.test.demohub.site/trunk/wp-config.php",
            "regexp": "WP_DEBUG",
            "search_string": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "state": "present",
            "unsafe_writes": false,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "block": "no",
        "cdn_id": "EZ0IYUPSOHOR4",
        "document_root": "trunk",
        "max_children": 1,
        "mysql8": true,
        "name": "www.test.demohub.site",
        "php_fpm_port": 9409,
        "php_version": "7.4",
        "user": "www_testdemohub"
    },
    "msg": ""
}
```

Firstmatch seems to work correctly, because the 2nd instance of define('WP_DEBUG is not changed to true. However the line is not inserted.

How can I insert this line, while not touching the 2nd line in the file that matches my regex as well?

Comment: In short: don't use lineinfile, use a template or eventually blockinfile. `insertafter` is only used when the line does not exist anywhere in your file and has to be inserted.